# Show attached files path in Grid in WPF

Tags: wpf

I am working on a WPF application.

Please check this image :

[image: screenshot]

When I will click on the + sign button, I want to show attached file path in the below grid.
For this I have done some work which I am showing you below.

#### XAML File

```
<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Appctr:GridToolBar x:Name="attachmentTool" Grid.Row="0" RemoveRowClick="attachmentTool_RemoveRowClick" AddRowClick="attachmentTool_AddRowClick" MoveUpClick="attachmentTool_MoveUpClick" MoveDownClick="attachmentTool_MoveDownClick" ToolBtn_Search="ButtonEditSettings_attachmentUsedClick" Height="25" />
    </StackPanel>
    <dxg:GridControl x:Name="dxgAttachment" Height="200" AutoPopulateColumns="False" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" >
        <dxg:GridControl.View>
            <dxg:TableView x:Name="vwAttachment" ShowGroupPanel="False" AllowBestFit="True" AutoWidth="True">
            </dxg:TableView>
        </dxg:GridControl.View>
        <dxg:GridControl.Columns>
            <!--<dxg:GridColumn FieldName="SlNo" Header="Sl #"></dxg:GridColumn>-->
            <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="LocalPath" Header="Attachment Path" Width="Auto" ReadOnly="True" EditSettings="{dxe:TextSettings TextWrapping=Wrap}"></dxg:GridColumn>
            <!--<dxg:GridColumn FieldName="LocalPath" Header="Attachment Path" Width="1130" ReadOnly="True" EditSettings="{dxe:TextSettings TextWrapping=Wrap}"></dxg:GridColumn>-->
        </dxg:GridControl.Columns>
    </dxg:GridControl>
</StackPanel>
```

#### .CS File

```
private void attachmentTool_AddRowClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();

    // Set filter for file extension and default file extension
    //dlg.DefaultExt = ".txt";
    //dlg.Filter = "Text documents (.txt)|*.txt";

    // Display OpenFileDialog by calling ShowDialog method
    Nullable<bool> result = dlg.ShowDialog();

    // Get the selected file name and display in a TextBox
    if (result == true)
    {
        try
        {
            // Open document
            string filePath = dlg.FileName;
            AttachmentInfo info = new AttachmentInfo();
            info.LocalPath = filePath;
            info.FileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filePath);
            info.FileExtension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(filePath).Replace(".", "");
            Stream strm = dlg.OpenFile();
            byte[] data = new byte[strm.Length];
            strm.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
            info.AttachmentContent = data;
            strm.Close();
            strm.Dispose();
            this.dxgAttachment.ItemsSource = info;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            DXMessageBox.Show("Unable to attach file. " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

#### Problem

1. How can I show attached file path in the grid?
2. After attachment of single or multiple files I also want to save all files in database as well. How to do this?

By using the above code I am not able to show the list of attached files in grid.

Comment: Your question is not a question at the moment. What exactly isn't working?

Comment: Please check now i have edited it.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what kind of DataGrid you're using, but the ItemsSource should probably be an IEnumerable (a collection of items) and not just a single item.

Try this:

```
this.dxgAttachment.ItemsSource = new List<AttachmentInfo>() { info };
```